# Call a SignalR method from a different AppDomain

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, appdomain

I have a working web server written in C# using SignalR. It's a self-hosted Owin Application. Everything works fine.

Now I have to relocate my controllers in different AppDomains. This breaks the SignalR part, because `GlobalHost` remains the same only within one AppDomain, and is not serializable (thus I can't pass it along to other AppDomains as it is).

I've found a lot of examples/questions/tutorials about calling SignalR hubs methods from a Controller/an other class/whatever, but nothing from outside the Default AppDomain (the one where the Owin application is initialized).

How can I send a message to a client from a controller set in a different AppDomain than the Hub ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is pretty simple: as for any inter-AppDomain communication, we need something that can cross the boundaries of an AppDomain, thus data or a proxy to a class.

Hence, the following works:

1. Create a class extending MarshalByRefObject: this will automatically create a proxy to this class when we pass it to a other class in a different AppDomain

   ```
   public class InterAppDomainForSignalR : MarshalByRefObject
   {
       public void Publish(PublishParameter param) {
           var clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TradeHub>().Clients;
           dynamic chan;
           if (param.group != null && param.group.Length > 0)
           {
               chan = clients.Group(param.group, param.ids);
           }
           else
           {
               if(param.ids == null || param.ids.length = 0) {
                   return; //not supposed to happen
               }
               chan = clients.Client(param.ids[0]);
           }
           chan.OnEvent(param.channelEvent.ChannelName, param.channelEvent);
       }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class PublishParameter
   {
       public string group { get; set; }
       public string[] ids { get; set; }
       public ChannelEvent channelEvent { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Make sure your parameters are `Serializable`: here, `PublishParameter` is obviously correct, BUT `ChannelEvent` has to be serializable too, and contain only `Serializable` members, etc...

2. Create an instance of this class and pass it to the objects in different AppDomains (`communicationChannel` is an instance of `InterAppDomainForSignalR`):

   ```
   AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(myDomainName);

   Type type = typeof(ClassInOtherAppDomain);
   ClassInOtherAppDomain startpoint = (ClassInOtherAppDomain)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
           type.Assembly.FullName,
           type.FullName) as ClassInOtherAppDomain;

   var session = startpoint.initialize(communicationChannel);
   ```
3. Store the `communicationChannel` in the `ClassInOtherAppDomain` instance, and use it at will ;) :

   ```
   public class ClassInOtherAppDomain {
       private InterAppDomainForSignalR communicationChannel { get; set; }

       public void initialize(InterAppDomainForSignalR communicationChannel) {
           this.communicationChannel = communicationChannel;
       }

       public void Publish(PublishParameter param) {
           this.communicationChannel.Publish(param);
       }
   }
   ```

That's it =)

More documentation on how to implement inter-AppDomain communication can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617506/Inter-Application-Domain-Communication) and [here](https://bitlush.com/blog/executing-code-in-a-separate-application-domain-using-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

From outside:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YOURHUBCLASS>();
context.Clients.All.yourHubTask();
```

Comment: I assume `YOURCLASSNAME` refers to the hub class.
There is no way this is going to work: the hub is already launched in the same AppDomain as the Owin application. The problem I have is: how to call something present inside the Owin application's AppDomain from a service running in a different AppDomain.

Comment: ```GlobalHost``` is a static variable, thus it has the same "value" only within an AppDomain.


So if my Owin application is launched in AppDomain 1, and I call ```GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YOURHUBCLASS>().Clients.All``` in AppDomain 2, I won't see any client: they are all registered in AppDomain 1...

Your answer works fine if used in the same AppDomain as the Owin application, but that is not my use-case.

Comment: Why can you not call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(YOURHUBCLASS).Assembly.FullName)` in AppDomain 2?

Comment: I wouldn't have access to the Clients: they are connected to the class existing in AppDomain 1.